# My firebase extension is failing to install due to invalid field values, but I don't see whats wrong with them?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, mailchimp, firebase-extensions

I am trying to install a mailchimp extension on firebase.

### my users firestore looks like this:

[image]

### My extension config looks like this:

[image]

### Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Do you have `/users/{documentId}/{documentId}` anywhere in the config? All paths should point towards a document only iirc.

Comment: @Dharmaraj thanks for the reply! Every path in the config is `/users/{documentId}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add the extra `{documentId}` to the end of your collection name -- looks like the extension is trying to add another one on for you and getting confused.

Try just setting your collection to `/users` and see if that fixes it.